# Why does "gcloud sql connect" take so long?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

What is the quickest way to open a command-line interface to a Google Cloud SQL database?

I like the old-school mysql command line interface, so currently I open a terminal from the cloud console and then connect with `gcloud sql connect ...`. This then shows a message "Allowlisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes.." which then sits for well over than a minute before the password prompt is given.

Compounding things, the cloud console disconnects if you leave the tab for 10 minutes so you have to do it all over again.

Are there any options to more quickly open a mysql command line client for quick queries? Should I spin up a linux server and connect from there? Load a MySQL client on my PC and connect from there? All of those are extra steps that I have to figure out, so I was wondering which connection method will give me the quickest connection speed just for simple querying.

Comment: Is the App Engine and Cloud SQL instance in the same location? Are you located near the region of your instances? Are you using the native drivers to connect to SQL?

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola I just click on the instance in the google console, then go to "Connect to this Instance", and then click "OPEN CLOUD SHELL". It says "provisioning your google cloud shell machine" and gives me a nice unix shell. Then from there I use "gcloud sql connect" with my instance name. This last part is the slow step, which takes minutes just to get the MySQL password prompt. So, I assume Google puts the shell in the same region/location as the database and also that it is using the native drivers from that shell. Thanks.

Comment: Did you create the SQL database using GCP? When you create an SQL database, you are asked the region where you want the database you want to be [Deployed](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/create-manage-databases]).  You need to generate a public address in your database (for me it's easier to use a public IP address) and make sure your firewall is configured to accept the communication from the database.  Here is a video that I used to connect a database to [my database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiJkEAfvFUc).

Comment: Here is a good document that can help you to connect your database client from a                                                                                             [local machine or compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#local). Try connecting using the                                           [Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy), it is the recommended method for connecting to a cloud SQL instance.

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola I created it all in the console. I do have Cloud SQL Auth Proxy installed and use it for local development with firebase function emulator. I should also just keep it running and then connect it with mysql workbench, that's a good idea. Go ahead and post "Use Cloud SQL Auth Proxy with a local database client, but just keep the proxy running" as an answer and I'll accept that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cloud SQL Auth Proxy with a local database client, but just keep the proxy running